# dnsmasq: assign nameserver override from nameserver with dynamic ip?

Tags: dnsmasq

I have a scenario where I connect to a handful of internal domains and I've been using dnsmasq to resolve those from our internal nameserver--the problem is that the nameserver's IP can change.  NetworkManager picks up the change but I don't know how to keep my `server` entries (e.g. `server=/wiki.internal.com/10.21.3.20`) in `dnsmasq.conf` up to date, since they are hard-coded in the config file.  I could read `/etc/NetworkManager/resolv.conf` and `sed` the `dnsmasq.conf`, but that's messy and manual.  Is there an automatic way to set up the IP that those entries point to?

Comment: What does resolv.conf has of information relevant to the dnsmasq.conf file? I mean, what do you get from there to possibly sed into dnsmasq?

Comment: `resolv.conf` has the nameserver IPs that NetworkManager found, those I need to put into my `server` directive in `dnsmasq.conf`